# Error 405 al usar fetch en javascript

Tags: javascript, php

estoy teniendo un problema tratando de enviar informacion desde JS a un API de php

Estoy usando el localstorage que es el que voy a enviar a el archivo php, en el html presiono enviar y activa lo siguiente

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(localStorage));

if (val) {
    confirmacion = confirm("Revisa tu infomacion que si intentas regresar, se borrara! :c");   
    
    //gen id y realizar post a php
    idGen();
    toPHP();
}

//console.log(localStorage);

function toPHP(){
    fetch('base.php',{
         method: 'POST',
         body: JSON.stringify(localStorage)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
     })
}

function idGen(){
     let id = '';
     for(let i =0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
         id += Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
     }
     localStorage.setItem("id",id);
}
```

Y mi archivo de php es el siguiente:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");

$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','pruebal');
$db->query("SET NAMES utf8");

$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$grade = $_POST['grade'];
$group = $_POST['group'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO general VALUES(
        '{$id}','{$name}','{$lastName}',
        '{$grade}','{$group}','{$age}','{$mail}');";
$save = $db->query($sql);

if($save){
    echo json_encode('Exito!');
}else{
    echo json_encode('Error!');
}

?>
```

El error que recibo es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por si las dudas, esto lo estoy trabajando en la carpeta htdocs y con xampp ya con apache y mysql activos, y la aplicación la corro con Live Server en VSCode, me puse a investigar, pero no recibo nada contundente o a lo mejor no entiendo del todo, pero ya intenté de mil formas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que JSON significa un elemento en el que asocias `{"clave" : "valor"}`  o un array de valores `["valor1", "valor2", "valorN"]`.

Al hacer esto:

```
echo json_encode('Exito!');
```

O esto:

```
echo json_encode('Error!');
```

No estarías produciendo un JSON válido para consumirlo en el cliente.

Intenta así:

```
$outPut=array();
$outPut['msg'] = ($save) ? 'Exito!' : 'Error!';
echo json_encode($outPut);
```

Así, vas a tener un JSON válido que será, según el caso:

```
{
   "msg":"Éxito!"
}
```

O:

```
{
   "msg":"Error!"
}
```

**Esto sería lo más lógico**, es decir, un texto asociado a una clave llamada `msg`, y para mostrarlo allí donde recibes la respuesta harías algo como esto: `laRespuesta.msg`, donde `laRespuesta` representa a tu JSON.

También puedes hacer algo como esto (aunque no es recomendable para este caso):

```
$outPut = ($save) ? array('Exito!') : array('Error!');
echo json_encode($outPut);
```

El resultado será también un JSON válido con esto:

```
["Exito!"]
```

O con esto:

```
["Error!"]
```

Y para consumirlo: `laRespuesta[0]`, donde `laRespuesta` representaría a tu JSON. Pero **esto es menos lógico**, porque no estamos hablando de una colección de cosas, sino de una respuesta simple. Si fuera una colección o una lista tendría sentido, porque podrías por ejemplo obtener cada elemento dentro de un bucle.